# Loud noises coming from my sump pump

Tags: sump-pump, pump

We moved into our house a few years back, and just now the sump pump started to make loud rattling noise when running. It is as if someone is banging on the pipes with a large piece of metal.

I have not been able to watch it run and witness the issue because it takes forever to fill the sump with water. I tried probing the pump, the pipes and whatever is around it, but everything looked solid.

Has anybody of you had that issue? Is that something I could fix on my own or do I need to call a plumber? What could that be so I have something to explain to the plumber if it comes to calling one?

Comment: Have you watched it run, and tried to locate the source of the sound? Is the discharge pipe securely fastened in place? Is there anything in contact with the discharge pipe?  Is the pump running more often?  Does the pump move water?

Comment: I have not been able to watch it run because it takes forever to fill the sump with water. I tried probing the pump, the pipes and whatever is around it, but everything looked solid. _I am going to add that to the question for clarity_

Comment: If you want to watch it run you can just pour a bucket of water into the sump.

Answer (score 1):

Most often, a rattling sound could be a piece of debris that is not getting fully lifted and ejected out with the water, like a small rock. Also, some pumps come with internal backwater valves that can become loose or broken and cause rattling.  And a third possible cause would be the bearings or stator giving out on the motor. 
I recently replaced my third sump pump over seven years of using them (year 1, 4 and 7). I would estimate the life expectancy for a pump that I use to be about 3 years.